# Data type mismatch in criteria expression when querying database

Tags: vb.net, types, mismatch

I'm a student currently doing my programming coursework. I am trying to get the `MemberID` from the Access database using a button in my `DataGridView`, but I end up with an error `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` when I select the member I wish to view. This is my code below:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim Member As String

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Conn)


    Connect = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = \\DRS-SR-002\RMShared Documents\Computer Programming\Programs\year13\Kevin\Project\Database tables\DBTables.accdb"
    Conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Connect)

    If e.ColumnIndex <> 4 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim MemberSelectedID As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value

    GroupBox1.Show()

    Query = "SELECT MemberID FROM tblMember WHERE [MemberID] = """ & MemberSelectedID & """"
    Conn.Open()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Selected Member")
    Conn.Close()
    Member = ds.Tables("Selected Member").Rows(0).Item(0)
    TextBox1.Text = Query

End Sub
```

Comment: where u r getting this error? please specify.

Comment: @SanketS Probably at `da.Fill(ds, "Selected Member")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query is wrong.
It should be like this.

```
Query = "SELECT MemberID FROM tblMember WHERE [MemberID] = " & MemberSelectedID
```

OR

```
Query = "SELECT MemberID FROM tblMember WHERE [MemberID] = '" & MemberSelectedID & "'"
```

MemberID field is Integer so no need to specify it as string.
In SQL Server single quote `'` is used to specify string not double quote `"`.

Comment: The second one will throw an exception with the same error if `MemberId` is defined as `Numeric` at database level.

Comment: yes but it depends on field type. It will work if datatype is `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `MemberSelectedID` from the `DataGridView` as `String` and then using it to query the database, on which I assume that it is defined as `Numeric`. That's the reason of the data type mismatch error

Try:

```
Dim MemberSelectedID As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
```

And

```
Query = "SELECT MemberID FROM tblMember WHERE MemberID = " & MemberSelectedID
```